# Jacoco Integration test report, getting error as Source file was not found during generation of report

Tags: integration, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, jacoco-plugin

In our Maven Multimodule project, I am running the application in local. Jacoco-it.exec file got generated. I am trying to generate the html file to view the integration test report, using the below command
`java -jar /Users/muru.s/Documents/jacoco-0.8.11/lib/jacococli.jar report /Users/muru.s/Documents/jacoco-it.exec --classfiles /Users/muru.s/Documents/app/app-core/app/target/classes --classfiles /Users/muru.s/Documents/app/app-revert/target/classes --sourcefiles /Users/muru.s/Documents/app/app-core/bpi/src/main/java/app/spi/rms/implementation/AuthToken.java --html /Users/muru.s/Documents/`

However it is still showing as
Source file "app/spi/rms/implementation/AuthToken.java" was not found during generation of report.

Comment: Issue fixed. After providing the "--sourcefiles /Users/muru.s/Documents/app/app-core/bpi/src/main/java"